# How to callback event load fontface?

Tags: javascript, css, fonts, dart, load

I want set callback when font-face is load done in DART.
For that, i use this code:

```
void myCallback() => print('Hello!');

FontFace font = new FontFace(Name, FontFileName);
document.fonts.add(font);

document.fonts.ready.then(myCallback); // ERROR IN DART PROPERTY 'READY' NOT KNOWN
```

The function **`document.fonts.ready.then(myCallback);`** only work in JavaScript, but in DART the object **`document.fonts.ready`** is not known by the compiler.

I found a property returning an element **`Future`** ​​and a method also returning a **`Future`** object, but I am not sure if this will help me and how serve.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: `ready` seems to be a property of `FontFaceSet` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FontFaceSet/ready, not `FontFace` not of `FontFace` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FontFace, but something like `font.load().then(myCallback);` should work, but also doesn't. 
`Uncaught TypeError: font.load(...).then$1 is not a function` https://dartpad.dartlang.org/b2de46ca423f6342e4d7c63a68f744aa Consider creating a bug report in http://dartbug.com/new.

Comment: You can always use dart-js-interop to work around such limitations.